# struggling with object oriented programming

Tags: php, jquery, json, oop

I'm trying to convert my php code into OOP. I'm using Datatables with jquery en ajax + JSON to load projects into a table. But i want to convert this code into OOP, but i always get a invalid json response. Im new into writing OOP, so could anyone help me out whats wrong with my code? I am trying to build one class around this codet. Can anybody help or make a skeleton for me, so i know what i do wrong?
This is the code :

```
/**
* Class project
*/


class Project {

    private $sql


// Get project (and id)
$project = '';
$id  = '';
if (isset($_GET['project'])){
  $project = $_GET['project'];
  if ($project == 'get_projecten' ||
      $project == 'get_project'   ||
      $project == 'add_project'   ||
      $project == 'edit_project'  ||
      $project == 'delete_project'){
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      if (!is_numeric($id)){
        $id = '';
      }
    }
  } else {
    $project = '';
  }
}

// Prepare array
$mysql_data = array();

// Valid job found
if ($project != ''){

  // Connect to database
  $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $result  = 'error';
    $message = 'Failed to connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    $project    = '';
  }

  // Execute job
  public function get_projecten ($project == 'get_projecten'){

    // Get projecten
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY projectid";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);

    if (!$query){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'query error';
    } 
    else {
      $result  = 'success';
      $message = 'query success';

      while ($project = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $test = '<a href="tasks.php" data-name="' . $project['projectnaam'] . '">' . $project['projectnaam'] . '</a>';
        $functions  = '<div class="function_buttons"><ul>';
        $functions .= '<li class="function_edit"><a data-id="'   . $project['projectid'] . '" data-name="' . $project['projectnaam'] . '"><span>Edit</span></a></li>';
        $functions .= '<li class="function_delete"><a data-id="' . $project['projectid'] . '" data-name="' . $project['projectnaam'] . '"><span>Delete</span></a></li>';
        $functions .= '</ul></div>';

        $mysql_data[] = array(
          "projectid"      => $project['projectid'],
          "projectnaam"    => $test,
          "startdatum"     => $project['startdatum'],
          "einddatum"      => $project['einddatum'],
          "omschrijving"   => $project['omschrijving'],
          "functions"      => $functions

        );
      }
    }

  } public function get_project ($project == 'get_project'){

    if ($id == ''){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'id missing';
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projectid = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $id) . "'";
      $query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
      if (!$query){
        $result  = 'error';
        $message = 'query error';
      } else {
        $result  = 'success';
        $message = 'query success';
        while ($project = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
          $mysql_data[] = array(
            "projectid"      => $project['projectid'],
            "projectnaam"    => $project['projectnaam'],
            "startdatum"     => $project['startdatum'],
            "einddatum"      => $project['einddatum'],
            "omschrijving"   => $project['omschrijving']
          );
        }
      }
    }

  } public function add_project ($project == 'add_project'){

    // Add project

    $projectid = $_GET['projectid'];
    $projectnaam =$_GET['projectnaam'];
    $startdatum =$_GET['startdatum'];
    $einddatum =$_GET['einddatum'];
    $omschrijving =$_GET['omschrijving'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO projects (projectid, projectnaam, startdatum, einddatum, omschrijving) VALUES (".$projectid.",'".$projectnaam."', '".$startdatum."', '".$einddatum."', '".$omschrijving."')";

    $query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);    
    if (!$query){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'query error';
    } else {
      $result  = 'success';
      $message = 'query success';
    }

  } 


 public function edit_project ($project == 'edit_project'){

    // Edit project
    if ($id == ''){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'id missing';

    } else {

         $projectid = $_GET['projectid'];
         $projectnaam =$_GET['projectnaam'];
         $startdatum =$_GET['startdatum'];
         $einddatum =$_GET['einddatum'];
         $omschrijving =$_GET['omschrijving'];


      $sql = "UPDATE projects SET projectnaam='".$projectnaam."', startdatum='".$startdatum."', einddatum='".$einddatum."', omschrijving='".$omschrijving."' WHERE projectid =".$projectid;

      $query  = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
      if (!$query){
        $result  = 'error';
        $message = 'query error';
      } else {
        $result  = 'success';
        $message = 'query success';
      }
    }

  } 

  public function delete_project ($project == 'delete_project'){

    // Delete project
    if ($id == ''){
      $result  = 'error';
      $message = 'id missing';
    } else {
      $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE projectid = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $id) . "'";
      $query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);
      if (!$query){
        $result  = 'error';
        $message = 'query error';
      } else {
        $result  = 'success';
        $message = 'query success';
      }
    }

  }

  // Close database connection
  mysqli_close($db_connection);

}


// Prepare data
$data = array(
  "result"  => $result,
  "message" => $message,
  "data"    => $mysql_data
);


// Convert PHP array to JSON array
$json_data = json_encode($data);
echo $json_data;    
?>
```

Comment: You have to put code into a method of a class, you cannot just plonk it in anywhere. [Start with a little reading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: @Niels I don't think it works the way you think it does. OOP is not about just putting your procedural code into classes. For example, create a database class first, which will work with any query and return the results and then use this class in your project.

Comment: i found so many errors in your code. needs lots of explanation. class is a collection of methods. Place all your methods inside the class. Only methods and variables used by methods should be in class. Remove other logics from the class. ex: `class Project {

  private $sql;

  public function get_projecten (){

  } 

  public function get_project (){

  } 

  public function add_project (){

  } 


  public function edit_project (){

  } 

  public function delete_project (){

  }

}`